# Exclude one point distribution from another

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm an absolute newbie at Blender and 3d, and I'm trying to build a scene using geometry nodes.  My problem is that this grass intersects the trees.

Is it possible to mix point distribution nodes to substract the tree points from the distribution density of the grass points?

It would be cooler with less grass under the trees because the lack of light under the trees doesn't allow grasses to grow as well.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: i am not sure whether this is already automatically possible with geometry nodes. But i am pretty sure this is possible with animation nodes.

Comment: if you ask the question again - i can give you a solution i found now in geometry nodes. I cannot reopen the question, but you can repeat your question ;)

Comment: I'm voting to reopen since this is tagged for geometry nodes.  It should get a node-based solution.

Comment: solution here as yt tutorial: https://youtu.be/T3V9JLbmumY